# Parsing using DOM parser

Tags: android, web-services, xml-parsing

```
        Visit_all_class parser = new Visit_all_class(); 
        String xml = parser.Call3(URL); // getting XML 
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element 

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_VISIT); 

        // looping through all item nodes <item> 
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) { 
            // creating new HashMap 

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
            Log.v("map","map" +map);
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i); 
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value 
            map.put(KEY_ACCOUNTNUMBER, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ACCOUNTNUMBER)); 
            map.put(KEY_LOCATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LOCATION)); 
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME)); 
            map.put(KEY_VISITID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_VISITID)); 
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_LAST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LAST));
            map.put(KEY_PLANNED, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PLANNED));
            map.put(KEY_COMPLETION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COMPLETION));
            map.put(KEY_START, parser.getValue(e, KEY_START));
            map.put(KEY_STATUS, parser.getValue(e, KEY_STATUS));


            // adding HashList to ArrayList 
            menuItems1.add(map);
```

I have parsed the values from webservice and put it together in menuItems. But, I want to parse values individually from the webservice and pass it in a method created for a Database.

Please suggest methods for how to parse values individually from webservice.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the `org.w3c.dom.Document` is formatted, but you use the methods from the `org.w3c.dom.Node` interface. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html).

For example, if you're expecting the XML to be formatted like this:

```
...
<visit>
    <account_no>1234</account_no>
    <location>www.example.com/locaiton1</location>
    <name>Ammu</name>
</visit>
<visit>
    <account_no>4321</account_no>
    <location>www.example.com/locaiton2</location>
    <name>William</name>
</visit>
...
```

you'd do:

```
Element e = (Element) nl.item(i); 
int accountNo = (int) e.getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent();
String location = e.getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent();
String name = e.getChildNodes().item(2).getTextContent();
```